# How to do an inner join in Prisma ORM?

Tags: prisma

Let there be 2 relations `A` and `B`.
There's a 1:n relationship, where for each `A` there can be multiple `B`s.
This means that `B` has a foreign key to `A`.

How do I using Prisma ORM query to find all `B`s with their `A` that have an `A` (so exclude all `B`s that don't have an `A`)?

In SQL it would be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "B" INNER JOIN "A" ON "A".id = "B".a_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Models should be declared this way:

```
model A {
  id Int @id
  b B[]
}

model B {
  id Int @id
  a_id Int
  a A @relation(fields: [a_id], references: [id])
}
```

and the query could be this one

```
const a = await prisma.a.findMany({
  // bring back the related B's
  include: {
    b: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's an `OUTER JOIN`.